# Replace nth and (n+1)th values in one file with same values from another file

Tags: awk

i have two files:

f1.txt:

```
header 1
header 2
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
```

f2.txt:

```
header 1
header 2
10
1234
5678
10
10
2345
6789
10
10
3456
7890
10
10
```

desired output

f3.txt:

```
header 1
header 2
100
1234
5678
100
100
2345
6789
100
100
3456
7890
100
100
```

the values in f2.txt that occur in lines 4 & 5, then 8 & 9, then 12 & 13 (i.e., they're spaced every 6th row), i want to put them inside f1.txt to replace the corresponding rows in f1.txt. how can i do this?

so far, i have only been able to print these values out of f2.txt as such:

```
exec<f2.txt
var=$(awk 'NR % 6 == 4')
echo "$var"
```

this produces

```
1234
2345
3456
```

then when i change 4 to 5, it gives me the 2nd set of values. so am trying to learn how to extract the 2 sets of values, and then put them in f1.txt? any help will be greatly appreciated.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
paste f1.txt f2.txt | awk -F'\t' '
    NR < 3 || (NR-2)%4 == 1 || (NR-2)%4 == 0 {print $1; next}
    {print $2}
'
```

Your desired output does not indicate groups of 6 lines, but instead groups of 4 lines. Perhaps the 2 header lines are throwing you off.

I'm assuming your input files do not contain tabs.

---

More concise awk from Ed Morton:

```
awk -F'\t' '{print (NR-2)%4 < 2 ? $1 : $2}'
```

Comment: `NR < 3 || (NR-2)%4 == 1 || (NR-2)%4 == 0` = `(NR-2)%4 < 2`. You could just write it as a ternary `awk -F'\t' '{print ((NR-2)%4 < 2 ? $1 : $2)}'`

Comment: Thank you very much! :-)